# Not able to transfer data from debezium mongodb source to mysql sink

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc, mongodb-kafka-connector

I want to transfer data from mongodb to mysql using kafka-connect. Example of record in uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production is:-

```
{"_id": {"id": 6},"amount": 6000,"booking_status": "BOOKED","destination_station": "New Delhi","journey_date": {"$date": "2023-03-20T20:15:48.175Z"},"last_modified": {"$date": "2023-03-20T20:15:48.175Z"},"number_of_passengers": 4,"source_station": "Howrah","ticket_number": "fcf1ef67-1900-41b1-95d4-59c61e80452a","train_number": 12301}
```

I want this data to get transferred in a table of mysql database table uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_thinclient whose structure is

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| amount               | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| booking_status       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| destination_station  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| journey_date         | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_modified        | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| number_of_passengers | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source_station       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ticket_number        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| train_number         | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The mongodb source connector I have used is

```
{
"name": "MongoDbSourceConnector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "mongodb.hosts": "debezium/localhost:27017",
    "mongodb.user": "sudhir",
    "mongodb.password": "password",
    "mongodb.name": "dbserver2",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
    }
}
```

After uploading this a topic `server_name.database_name.collection_name`  is created, which in my case is `dbserver2.uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production` .

In topic, data gets published in `after` property in string format.

The mysql jdbc sink connector I have used is

```
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "topics": "dbserver2.uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect",
    "connection.user": "root",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "table.name.format": "uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_thinclient",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "db.timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
  }
}
```

The ERROR I am getting is

> `INFO Setting metadata for table "uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect"."booking_journal_thinclient" to Table{name='"uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect"."booking_journal_thinclient"', type=TABLE columns=[Column{'id', isPrimaryKey=true, allowsNull=false, sqlType=INT}, Column{'booking_status', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'number_of_passengers', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=INT}, Column{'train_number', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=INT}, Column{'journey_date', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=DATETIME}, Column{'amount', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=DOUBLE}, Column{'source_station', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'ticket_number', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=false, sqlType=VARCHAR}, Column{'last_modified', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=DATETIME}, Column{'destination_station', isPrimaryKey=false, allowsNull=true, sqlType=VARCHAR}]} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.TableDefinitions:64)[2023-04-17 17:51:20,692] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=JdbcSinkConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Unsupported source data type: STRUCT (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:612)org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unsupported source data type: STRUCTat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.bindField(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1609)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialect.bindField(DatabaseDialect.java:608)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindField(PreparedStatementBinder.java:186)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindKeyFields(PreparedStatementBinder.java:154)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindRecord(PreparedStatementBinder.java:102)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:184)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:109)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:74)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:84)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)[2023-04-17 17:51:20,693] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=JdbcSinkConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:614)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unsupported source data type: STRUCTat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.bindField(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1609)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialect.bindField(DatabaseDialect.java:608)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindField(PreparedStatementBinder.java:186)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindKeyFields(PreparedStatementBinder.java:154)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindRecord(PreparedStatementBinder.java:102)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:184)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:109)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:74)at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:84)`

Answer (score 0):

The `id` and timestamp fields cannot be stored in JDBC Sink connector, as they are (as objects / STRUCT types). You'll need extra transforms to "unwrap" those.

Comment: Can you please share how to approach this. I am a beginner in this

Comment: I don't use Debezium, so I don't know. I only know the JDBC sink will only accept non-nested data... I think you should create an issue for Debezium since `UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope` should do this